# Writing a method which takes an instance of a Mute as a parameter and modifies its state to show that the class is mutable

Tags: java, oop, instance-variables, class-variables

I have been given a class (mute) that is mutable. I have to take an instance of this class in a `ModifyMute` class and show that it is mutable. I am struggling to get off the ground so far and would like to see how it can be done. I have to use a public static void method in the `ModifyMute` class as well. I also have to use the parameter mute in ModifyMute. Mute cannot be changed.

This is the `Mute` class:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Mute
{
   private int num;
   private Set<String> names;
  
   public Mute(int num, String name)
   {
      names = new HashSet<>();
      set.add(name);
   }
   
   public int getNum() {return this.num;}
   public Set<String> getNames() {return names;}
}
```

And this is the ModifyMute class I have to modify using the mute parameter.

```
public class ModifyMute
{
    public static void modifyMute(Mute mute)
    {
           
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you can't modify `Mute` class? If that is the case, then you can't change fields of it's objects directly. However, you can get the `Set` and modify that.

Comment: How do I go about getting the set? New to java and not sure how to access it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mute m = new Mute(1, "paul");
        System.out.printf("Number:%d Names:%s\n", m.getNum(), m.getNames());

        m.getNames().add("gon");
        System.out.printf("Number:%d Names:%s\n", m.getNum(), m.getNames());
    }
```

Assuming that Mute class cannot be modified, we can still update the names.

Output:

Number:0 Names:[paul]

Number:0 Names:[gon, paul]